Android: How to print EditText with font type and size by WebView
I use WebView to print the content in an EditText as the sample code below.
The print function works well but the different fonts and sizes , that were set in EditText, do not display in the print output. I tried to  change "text/plain" to "text/html" but it is still the same.
Please help if any suggestion. Thanks!
void printFile(){
    WebView myWebView = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
    myWebView.loadData(editText2.getText().toString(), "text/plain", "UTF-8");
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }
    });

    PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) primaryBaseActivity.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    //create object of print adapter
    PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = myWebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter();
    //provide name to your newly generated pdf file
    String jobName = getString(R.string.app_name) + " Print";
    //open print dialog
    printManager.print(jobName, printAdapter, new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
}

